# Gradle Jaxb Plugin Error Multiple Schemas and XJB

Tags: gradle, jaxb2, xjc

I'm using the [jacobono gradle-jaxb-plugin](https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin). I'm trying to generate classes from multiple schema files in a directory while using XJB to add an annotation to one of the classes. I'm seeing the following error:

```
[ant:xjc] [ERROR] "file:/src/test/xsd/XSD_ONE_1_0.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for "file:/src/test/xsd/XSD_TWO_1_0.xsd"?

[ant:xjc]   line 10 of file:/src/test/xsd/xjb/xsd-bindings.xjb
```

XJB File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox" version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../XSD_ONE_1_0.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='SomeNodeName']">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement"
                    name="someNodeName" />
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Folder structure:

```
src
  test
    xsd
      xjb
        xjb-bindings.xjb
      XSD_ONE_1_0.xsd
      XSD_TWO_1_0.xsd
```

Relevant plugin config:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7-b41'
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7-b41'
    jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.7'
    jaxb "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-ant:0.6.5"
    jaxb "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:0.6.4"
    jaxb "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-annotate:0.6.4"
    jaxb "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-value-constructor:3.0"
}

jaxb {
    xsdDir = "${project.name}/src/test/xsd"
    bindingsDir = "${project.name}/src/test/xsd/xjb"
    bindings = ["xsd-bindings.xjb"]

    xjc {
        taskClassname = "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task"
        destinationDir = "generated-sources/jaxb"
        args = ["-Xinheritance", "-Xannotate", "-Xvalue-constructor"]
    }
}
```

I did try removing the second xsd file, and then it seemed to work, but that's not going to be a permanent solution.

UPDATE:

I just found this person with the same issue that logged it as an issue on Github. This could just be a bug with the plugin. I'll have to take a look at the code.

https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin/issues/27

Comment: And the plugin config is?...

Comment: Added the Gradle plugin configuration above.